# Applying color with index in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object

Let's say i have array of the colors;

```
availableColors = ['#aee3d8', ' #d1caae', '#e7e1f9'];
```

and I have the array of the Objects with object like this.

```
[{
        name: 'Name',
        surname: 'Surname',
        timeOff: '8:05 AM',
        imageSource: null,
    };
{
        name: 'Name',
        surname: 'Surname',
        timeOff: '8:05 AM',
        imageSource: someUrl,
    };

{
        name: 'Name',
        surname: 'Surname',
        timeOff: '8:05 AM',
        imageSource: null,
    }]
```

How can I apply the different color by index when mapping user?

```
    public applyUserPictureColor(): void {
    this.users.push(this.user, this.user, this.user, this.user);
    const users = this.users.map((user) => {
        if (!user.imageSource) {
            return {
                ...user,
                bg: this.colorIndex(),
            };
        }
    });
this.users = users;
}



private colorIndex(): void {
        this.availableColors
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *apply different color by index*? Do you want the first user to have the first color, second second color, and so on and repeat those three colors until all users have a color assigned to them?

Comment: @Mushroomator yes. that's what i want. and when i will have in the middle user with photo, to not start from the beginning

Comment: in a forEach (and in map and in find) you can use a second argument: the index, e.g. `users = this.users.map((user,index)=>{return {...user,:bg:this.availableColors[index]}})`

Comment: Please check is it work for you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hmfeaw

Comment: @Abhishek it worked only if you have 3 users unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [Generator](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_sync-generators.html) and [Iterator](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_sync-iteration.html) to do this kind of thing.

This will always repeat the colors provided in the array given to `*getColor()` for however many users you have. It does this using and ininfite loop and [modular arithmetic](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

```js
const availableColors = ["#aee3d8", "#d1caae", "#e7e1f9"];

/**
 * Cyclic generator to always get the next color from a given range of colors.
 * @param {Array<string>} allColors
 */
function* getColor(allColors) {
  let i = 0;
  while (true) {
    yield allColors[i];
    i = (i + 1) % allColors.length;
  }
}

// get the iterator to be able to always get the next color
const iter = getColor(availableColors);

const users = [
  {
    name: "Name",
    surname: "Surname",
    timeOff: "8:05 AM",
    imageSource: "",
  },
  {
    name: "Name2",
    surname: "Surname",
    timeOff: "8:05 AM",
    imageSource: "",
  },
  {
    name: "Name3",
    surname: "Surname",
    timeOff: "8:05 AM",
    imageSource: "",
  },
  {
    name: "Name4",
    surname: "Surname",
    timeOff: "8:05 AM",
    imageSource: null,
  },
  {
    name: "Name5",
    surname: "Surname",
    timeOff: "8:05 AM",
    imageSource: "",
  },
  {
    name: "Name6",
    surname: "Surname",
    timeOff: "8:05 AM",
    imageSource: null,
  },
];

const usersWithColors = users.map(user => {
  // use iterator to get next color
  user.backgroundColor = iter.next().value;
  return user;
})

console.log(usersWithColors);
```

This will also not start at the *"beginning"* again like you want it to behave, except when you create a new iterator.

```js
const availableColors = ["#aee3d8", "#d1caae", "#e7e1f9"];

/**
 * Cyclic generator to always get the next color from a given range of colors.
 * @param {Array<string>} allColors
 */
function* getColor(allColors) {
  let i = 0;
  while (true) {
    yield allColors[i];
    i = (i + 1) % allColors.length;
  }
}

let iterator = getColor(availableColors);
for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
  console.log(iterator.next().value);
}
// the next value of iterator.next().value would be #e7e1f9
// but now we assign a new iterator and start from the beginning again
iterator = getColor(availableColors);
console.log("Start over...")
for (let index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
  console.log(iterator.next().value);
}
```

### Edit

As [Nick Parsons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5648954/nick-parsons) pointed out you can make the generator more elegant by using the following.

```js
/**
 * Cyclic generator to always get the next color from a given range of colors.
 * @param {Array<string>} allColors
 */
function* getColor(allColors) {
  while (true) yield* allColors;
}
```

Also if you want to treat your array as immutable, which you usually would like to do, you need to adjust the `map()` function as shown below.

```js
const usersWithColors = users.map(user => ({ ...user, backgroundColor: iter.next().value }))
```

Applying all of the above you will get to the following implementation:

```js
const availableColors = ["#aee3d8", "#d1caae", "#e7e1f9"];

/**
 * Cyclic generator to always get the next color from a given range of colors.
 * @param {Array<string>} allColors
 */
function* getColor(allColors) {
  while (true) yield* allColors;
}

// get the iterator to be able to always get the next color
const iter = getColor(availableColors);

const users = [
  {
    name: "Name",
    surname: "Surname",
    timeOff: "8:05 AM",
    imageSource: "",
  },
  {
    name: "Name2",
    surname: "Surname",
    timeOff: "8:05 AM",
    imageSource: "",
  },
  {
    name: "Name3",
    surname: "Surname",
    timeOff: "8:05 AM",
    imageSource: "",
  },
  {
    name: "Name4",
    surname: "Surname",
    timeOff: "8:05 AM",
    imageSource: null,
  },
  {
    name: "Name5",
    surname: "Surname",
    timeOff: "8:05 AM",
    imageSource: "",
  },
  {
    name: "Name6",
    surname: "Surname",
    timeOff: "8:05 AM",
    imageSource: null,
  },
];

const usersWithColors = users.map(user => ({ ...user, backgroundColor: iter.next().value }))
// this is now a new array
console.log("New array with background color information")
console.log(usersWithColors);
// users is not changed
console.log("Unchanged users")
console.log(users)
```

Comment: You could make your generator a little more concise by doing `function* getColor(allColors) {while (true) yield* allColors;}` :) . While it isn't wrong, I would probably also change the `.map()` to return a new object rather than modifying the `user` object, otherwise you end up modifying the original array (which OP might want to preserve)

Comment: Thanks. Good additions. I've included all of your suggestions in my edited answer.

Comment: @Mushroomator but what if i need to create check by imageSource field and will have 2 iteration operators, after that image source, (skip element with image url) and continue on next found element?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for tbh. The important thing here is more or less just the generator function. Whenever you need a color call `iter.next().value` and you will get the next color. If you don't need a color for an element just don't call `iter.next().value` for it.